# You have an error in your SQL syntax;..(in the alter command)

Tags: java, mysql, sql

Please tell me what causes error in this sql query given below:-

```
ALTER TABLE message ADD COLUMN sent_at timestamptz DEFAULT NOW();
```

Comment: **Pro tip:** Always read error messages carefully. I bet you this one says ` ... for the right syntax to use near 'timestamptz DEFAULT NOW();' ` somewhere in it.

Answer (score 2):

`timestamptz` is not a MySQL data type. `timestamp` is a MySQL data type.

Answer (score 0):

You have an error  don't need column

```
ALTER TABLE message ADD sent_at timestamptz DEFAULT NOW();
```